# Hide element by clicking body unless specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, click, bind

I have this javascript object:

```
StoryGroup = {
    groupInput: '.story-group-container input[type="text"]',
    container: '.checkbox-container',
    submit: '.checkbox-container .filter',
    body: 'body',
    init: function() {
        $(this.groupInput).click(this.showForm.bind(this));
        $(this.body).click(this.hideForm.bind(this));
    },
    showForm: function() {
        $(this.container).show();
    },
    hideForm: function(e) {
        if (e.currentTarget == $(this.groupInput) || e.currentTarget == $(this.container)) {
            $(this.container).show();
        } else {
            $(this.container).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this not working correctly? If I remove the 'hideForm' function.  The showForm function works properly and shows my 'container' when the groupInput is clicked.  I want to run the hideForm function when anywhere on the body is clicked unless that click is on the input or container. This is why i pass in the 'e' to make sure that the click is not on those two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the references, obviously both are not going to be the same in your case,

```
hideForm: function(e) {
   if (!($(e.currentTarget).is(this.groupInput) || $(e.currentTarget).is(this.container))) {
      $(this.container).hide();
   }
}
```

Try to use `.is(selector)` at this context.

Comment: that makes sense to me but it does not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: @JordanBarber Can you create a simple demo of your problem in jsfiddle.net ? So that it would be easy for us to fix it.

Comment: Yes, give me a few seconds

Comment: here you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZmVQJ?editors=1111.  You can see I have the hideForm function commented out.  Uncomment it and you will see nothing works

Comment: Also, in that link I have it switched back to using the references, but if you include your method you will see that does not work either.

Comment: @JordanBarber Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/cu0cvem2/ Made css changes with `html,body` selector and some js changes. Don't forget to upvote and accept. :) :)

Comment: @JordanBarber Glad to help! :)